# Placing a fixed position toolbar in a Split View Controller's root view

Tags: ipad

I am having a problem placing a tool bar in the root view controller for a split view IPad app.  I tried reducing the table view size and placing a toolbar under it, but the frame adjustment doesn’t take and the toolbar ends up scrolling with the table and not staying at the bottom of the screen like I want.

Here is the code that I am using in viewDidLoad:

self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, searchBar.bounds.size.height, 320, 655 -     searchBar.bounds.size.height);

UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 655, 320, 50);

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a nice solution to this problem, here is the code:

```
[super viewWillAppear: animated];

toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init]; toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 49);
[toolbar sizeToFit];

CGFloat toolbarHeight = 49;
CGRect rootViewBounds = self.parentViewController.view.bounds;
CGFloat rootViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rootViewBounds);
CGFloat rootViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rootViewBounds);

CGRect rectArea = CGRectMake(0, rootViewHeight - toolbarHeight, rootViewWidth, toolbarHeight);

[toolbar setFrame:rectArea];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];

[[self tableView] reloadData];
```

Comment: And the parent of the toolbar is an uinavigationcontroller?